# Does the gravitomagnetic model for frame dragging imply that objects be "sped up" to rotating speed based on their inertia?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, frame-dragging

As a specific example, consider a needle on a torsionless thread lowered from deep space over a rotating planet's pole.  The needle will spin at a specified rate (based on elevation, planet inertia and planet roational speed).  It seems like the needle in the space-time warp model would come to speed instantly (no acceleration involved) while in some sort of magnetic-analogy force field model, it would take time to come to speed based on the needle's moment of angular inertial.  Moreover, in the space-time warp model, there would be no sense of rotation.  If a piece broke off the tip of the needle, it would circle around (as seen from the planet).  If the spinning is caused by a force, it would seem to imply that the needle would feel rotational effects, and if the tip broke off, it would travel in a straight line.  Am I wrong, or do the two models for explaining frame dragging have these different consequences?

Comment: What is a “space-time warp model”?

Comment: It is a very shorthand reference to the descriptions of spacetime (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime) being distorted or rotated or warped so that objects are spun as seen from the planet below (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame-dragging).  This is usually accompanied by a drawing like the one at https://www.vice.com/en/article/8gmy4a/the-learning-corner-805-v18n5